# Show preview of image in form

Tags: django, image-uploading

I want to achieve the following in a django form, for a `models.ImageField`:

- do not show the standard `<input type="file">` button ("choose file" button)
- show a preview of the current image, for already populated models
- for empty (new) models, show a custom button
- clicking on the image preview or the custom button will open a file dialog to select the image from the user's file system
- selecting a new image replaces the custom button or the old image preview with the preview of the new image

This seems to me like a normal workflow to select images in a form, but I do not seem to find any fully working solution. All I can find involves hacking around several parts:

- styling the label and hiding the standard "choose file" button: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p2gTDZKS9Y
- use a widget instead of the standard for `forms.FileField`.

I have tried to use:

```
class ImagePreviewWidget(Widget):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return mark_safe('<img src="/media/%s" width="100px"/>' % escape(value))
```

For the widget, and I am using this in the form like this:

```
class DesignCampaignForm(ModelForm):

    brand_logo = FileField(widget=ImagePreviewWidget)
```

This is properly showing the preview of the existing image, but I am unable to click on it to select another file, and even if I was that would not update the preview.

Is there an already available solution for this simple use case?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't been able to find a complete solution, so I have done the following:

- use a widget to render a modified `ClearableFileInput`, rendering an image and an `<input>` element
- style the `<input>` in the element with CSS, to hide it
- make sure that clicking in the image triggers the hidden `<input>` element, wrapping the `<img>` in a `<label>` and using the `for` attribute
- add some javascript to replace the image preview whenever the selection in the `<input>` element changes
- whenever the selection is cleared, show the original preview

A gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/gonvaled/93f0d3c3f1063e1355b3).

In my final solution (not yet in the gist), I have added a button for when the image is not yet selected.

edit: Gist only works for Django before version 1.11.x.
`class ClearableFileInput` has since been gutted and changed

Comment: Cool gist, thanks! Best that I found for me. One that I want to ask you is make your link to gist more marked, because I have skipped it few time while rush searching over SO.